# Android - scrollTo() on ScrollView doesn't work properly

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using Titanium SDK 5.1.2.GA. I have a bar like TabGroup on Android and iOS. I move the scroll when a tab is not completely visible in the view and you click that tab.

On iOS works perfectly but on Android doesn't work fine.

This is my code to move the scroll view:

```
if((view.rect.x + view.rect.width) > (toolbarX + $.toolbar.rect.width)){
    $.toolbar.scrollTo(((view.rect.x + view.rect.width) - $.toolbar.rect.width) + 10, 0);
}else if(view.rect.x < toolbarX){
    $.toolbar.scrollTo(view.rect.x - 10, 0);
}
```

$.toolbar -> ScrollView

view -> tab

This photo explain my problem:

[image]

I've seen this JIRA ticket on Internet
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17954

This will be the problem??

**EDIT**

This problem is caused by the new unit system on Appcelerator.

I have this line on my tiapp.xml

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

but other functions on Titanium return their values on px, so that's a problem.

My question now is:

- What units return the event listeners like 'scroll'?? (px or dp)
  Because my `toolbarX = e.x` from scroll event
- What units need scrollTo(x,y)????

Comment: What is the problem with Android ? Maybe you must convert to coordinate dp to px on Android with this : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.builtins.measurement-method-dpToPX . If you use Alloy, you can use this widget that works perfectly (or look the widget code to solve your problem) https://github.com/manumaticx/pagingcontrol

Comment: Thank you @ThomasLemaitre I don't know this widget. I'll try it because dp to px doesn't work either

Comment: The ticket you link indeed seems to be the issue. But may I ask why you're building this with Views and ScrollViews instead of using the builtin TabGroup which looks exactly like your screenshot?

Comment: Because I need the same display on iOS. What units return scroll event?? px or dp?

Comment: And scrollTo()??? you have to put the units in px or dp???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
if(Alloy.Globals.isAndroid){
            var measure = require('alloy/measurement');

            //Vemos si tenemos que mover la toolbar
            if((view.rect.x + view.rect.width) > (toolbarX + $.toolbar.rect.width)){
                $.toolbar.scrollTo(((measure.dpToPX(view.rect.x) + measure.dpToPX(view.rect.width)) - measure.dpToPX($.toolbar.rect.width)) + 10, 0);
            }else if(view.rect.x < toolbarX){
                $.toolbar.scrollTo(measure.dpToPX(view.rect.x) - 10, 0);
            }
        }else{
            //Vemos si tenemos que mover la toolbar
            if((view.rect.x + view.rect.width) > (toolbarX + $.toolbar.rect.width)){
                $.toolbar.scrollTo(((view.rect.x + view.rect.width) - $.toolbar.rect.width) + 10, 0);
            }else if(view.rect.x < toolbarX){
                $.toolbar.scrollTo(view.rect.x - 10, 0);
            }
        }
    }

$.toolbar.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

    Ti.API.info("-- toolbarX: " + e.x + " / " + Alloy.Globals.measure.pxToDP(e.x));

    if(Alloy.Globals.isAndroid){
        toolbarX = Alloy.Globals.measure.pxToDP(e.x);
    }else{
        toolbarX = e.x;
    }
});
```

This problem is new because that:

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

Now, you have to GUESS in what units (px or dp) you have to pass the values on Android, because some functions return px and need px and the others dp.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    $.tabbar.scrollTo(Util.DPUnitsToPixels(x), 0);
} else {
    $.tabbar.scrollTo(x, 0);    
}
```

on android convert dp to pixel

Comment: And how you obtain the dp? are the default measure on android?